# VS Code command line with full path to list extension doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

This works

```
code --list-extensions
```

But this will launch VS Code instead

```
c:\install\Code.exe --list-extensions
```

How can I list extensions with VS Code's full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code.cmd` is a script which sets some environment variables and then runs Code.exe with some arguments; `Code.exe` is the VSCode executable.

To list extensions with full path, try

```
C:\install\bin\code.cmd --list-extensions
```

Running the code.cmd batch script launches Code.exe with a JavaScript file , `cli.js`, which handles the command-line arguments. However, running `Code.exe` directly doesn't handle the arguments, it just launches VSCode as you found out.

There is also a `code` script which is a Bourne shell script for launching VSCode from WSL<sup>[1]</sup> or Linux and macOS. This script also handles command-line arguments.

The `code.cmd` script is as follows in vscode 1.73.0:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VSCODE_DEV=
set ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
"%~dp0..\Code.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node %*
endlocal
```

1: Windows Subsystem for Linux